# There exist $k$ vertices with degree differences at most $k - 2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices.
Prove that, for every $k\in\{2,\dots,n\}$, there exist $k$ distinct vertices in $G$ whose degrees differ by at most $k-2$.

Comment: The wording still suggests one can **fix** $k$ to be, say, two. I *think* you want to write, "for *every* $k\ge2$ there exist $k$ vertices etc., etc."

Comment: @Gerry Myerson Yes, you are correct, I edit it now, I think everything is okay now.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "co.combinatorics". I added this tag now.

Comment: I should also add that this is a question-and-answer site. So next time, instead of saying in imperative "Prove that", ask a question like "Is it true that" In addition, motivate the question: how did it come up in your research, why do you need it, what partial results you have on it, what approaches you tried etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result was originally proved by [Erdős-Chen-Rousseau-Schelp (1993)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669883710231) using the [Erdős-Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem). A more direct proof (which seems to be identical to the one in 1001's response) was given by [Caro-Lauri-Zarb (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08303). The latter paper appeared in  Bull. Inst. Combin. Appl. 85 (2019), 79–91.

Comment: I think, only the easy direction of Erdős-Gallai theorem is used (that the inequalities for degrees are necessary, which is simply double counting of edges between two sets of vertices.)

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sure. Hence the two proofs are not that different, after all.

Answer (score 5):

For what it worth, there goes a short self-contained proof of this (belonging to Erdős-Chen-Rousseau-Schelp, as mentioned by GH) result.

Changing notations, I prove that there exist $k+1$ vertices with degrees differ by at most $k-1$, for every $k=1,\ldots,n-1$.

Let $d_i$ be degree of vertex $i$, so that $d_1\leqslant d_2\leqslant \ldots \leqslant d_n$. Assume that, on the contrary, $d_{i+k}\geqslant d_i+k$ for every $i=1,\ldots,n-k$. Let each vertex $k+1,\ldots,n$ send a postcard to every its neighbour. Then by our assumption they send at least $d_1+\ldots+d_{n-k}+k(n-k)$ postcards. On the other hand, each vertex $i$ for $i\leqslant n-k$ gets at most $d_i$ postcards, each vertex $j$ with $j>n-k$ gets at most $n-k$ postcards, and this inequality is strict for $j=n$. A contradiction.

Comment: I don't get last part of this proof. Please explain it more. What is the contradiction here?

Comment: The total number of *received* postcards is strictly less than $d_1+\ldots+d_{n-k}+k\cdot (n-k)$, thus less than the total number of *sent* postcards, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be the number of vertices of the graph. Take $k = n$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that the vertices don't have degree difference at most $n - 2$. Then there must be two vertices with degree difference at least $n - 1$. Since degrees lie between $0$ and $n - 1$, there must be vertices $u$ and $v$ with degrees $0$ and $n - 1$ respectively. This means $v$ is everyone's neighbor. However, that contradicts the fact that $u$ has no neighbors.

Note that the statement is false if $n = 1$ (and the proof doesn't work because in that case $u = v$).

For other $k$ we can solve the problem similarly. Again suppose such a graph $G$ exists.

We sort the vertices in order of degree sequence. Note that $d(v_{i+\lambda (k-1)}) - d(v_i) \geq \lambda (k - 1)$.

Let $\lambda = \lfloor (n - 1) / (k - 1) \rfloor$, $x = n - \lambda \cdot (k - 1)$ and $i \in [1,x]$.

Recall that $d(v_{i + \lambda(k - 1)}) \geq \lambda (k - 1) + d(v_i)$. Thus $v_{i + \lambda(k - 1)}$ is a neighbor of all but at most $x - d(v_i)$ vertices (including itself). Therefore the number of edges between the first and the last $x$ vertices is at least
$$x^2 - \sum_{i \in [1,x]} (x - 1 - d(v_i)) > \sum_{i \in [1,x]} d(v_i).$$
However the degree of the first $x$ vertices is not sufficiently high, which gives a contradiction.